# Customise single cell in UITableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I would like to change the format of the first `cell` in my `UITableView` (masterViewController), so that the `image` stretches across the`width` of the whole `cell` and the text label is shown above the image. Also would like to add a second text label to this `cell` only?

Any help on how to do this would be great, I have looked without success for this particular problem and I am fairly new to `UITableViews`.

Comment: use `CustomCell for indexpath.row == 0` and normal cell or other cells for next rows

Comment: Use Customcell: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-crafting-custom-uitableview-cells--mobile-15702.

Comment: if you don't have a tableheader.. why don't you make the tableHeader custom?

Answer (score 1):

Make one custom cell as per your requirement and load it for `indexpath.row== 0` and simple `UITableViewCell` for all other cells. hope it will helps you

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

CustomCell *customcell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

static NSString * identifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];


if(indexPath.row == k)
{
    if(customcell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        scrlcell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
}
else{
   if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
}
}

if(indexPath.row == k)
    return customcell;
else
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: i've added this but it does't recognise CustomCell? Is there something i need to do in storyboard to identifier name or something?

Comment: @burrGGG make xib for CustomCell. and give your cell identifier to `CustomCell`

Answer (score 0):

You should build a custom cell (you can build it in Interface builder) and then use it on your `indexPath.row == 0`. Like this:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if(!cell)
{
    NSArray *topLevel = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    for (id currentObject in topLevel){
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[CustomCell class]])
        {
            cell = currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if(indexPath.row == 0){
    // Use your cell here
}else{
   // Build a new cell
}

return cell;
```

Comment: you should also use a second identifier.

Comment: how would i actually implement this? in my cellForRowAtIndexPath?